# WCF: Passing Username and password to another service (No Https)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security, wcf-authentication

I have to Create a WCF service (ServiceWrapper), which references another WCF Service(RealService).

I want Clients of ServiceWrapper to pass Username/password in authentication request.

The Operations of ServiceWrapper Call RealService. I need to pass the recieved Username/passowrd to Authenticate with RealSerivce and then call its Operations.

I need to host the service on Http and not Https(SSL/TLS).

Question: How to use the Client Credentails Recieved by a Service to authenticate with a Referenced Service without using Https(SSL/TLS)?

Comment: Question: How to use the Client Credentails Recieved by a Service to authenticate with a Referenced Service without using Https(SSL/TLS)?

Answer (score 3):

Your can use SOAP security. There are two SecurityModes for you - Message, TransportWithMessageCredential.

1. You should configure security mode (UserName) in `<binding>` section like this

   ```
   <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
       <transport clientCredentialType="" />
       <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
   </security>
   ```
2. Next, you should specify custom validator in `<behavior>` section

   ```
   <behavior name="CommonBehavior">
       <serviceMetadata />
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
       <serviceCredentials>
           <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Megatec.MasterTourService.CustomUserNameValidator, Megatec.MasterTourService"/>

           <serviceCertificate findValue="WCFServer" storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
               storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
           <clientCertificate>
               <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
           </clientCertificate>
       </serviceCredentials>
   </behavior>
   ```
3. In your custom validator you can access and store user name and password, which were given as creditionals for ServiceWrapper.

   ```
   using System.ServiceModel;
   using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
   namespace MyService
   {
       public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
       {
           public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
           {
               if (!(userName == "testMan" && password == "pass"))
                   throw new FaultException("Incorrect login or password");

               // save your Usermame and Password for future usage.
            }
       }
   }
   ```
4. When you need to access RealService, you can use userName and password as credentials, like my example below:

   ```
   private readonly Dictionary<Type, Object> channelFactoryDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Object>();
   private ChannelFactory<T> GetChannelFactory<T>() where T : class
   {
       if (channelFactoryDictionary.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)))
           return channelFactoryDictionary[typeof(T)] as ChannelFactory<T>;

       var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>("*");
       channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
       channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;

       channelFactoryDictionary.Add(typeof(T), channelFactory);

       return channelFactory;
   }
   ```

Comment: Question: How to use the Client Credentails Recieved by a Service to authenticate with a Referenced Service without using Https(SSL/TLS)?

Comment: +1 In your step 3, I'd recommend storing the credentials in a custom OperationContext extension. That way, you're guaranteed that the stored values have the right lifetime (the duration of the service call). There's an [example here](http://hyperthink.net/blog/a-simple-ish-approach-to-custom-context-in-wcf/ "Example OperationContext extension").

Answer (score 1):

If SSL is not an option, you will need to use SOAP message security (SecurityMode = Message).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx